# Segfault with error 4 in pthread_create

Tags: c++, pthreads

I consistently receive following segfault with error 4 (which afaik is null pointer dereference by checking on https://rgeissert.blogspot.com/p/segmentation-fault-error.html):

```
Aug  6 11:42:54 mypc kernel: [28532305.723536] myapp-new[14784]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f642c6c5d44 sp 00007ffc6a937700 error 4 in libpthread-2.23.so[7f642c6bc000+18000]
```

Code is following:

```
void* request(void* p){
    // ... code
}

void Daemon::run(){

    pthread_attr_t attr; 
    pthread_attr_init(&attr); 
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    LOG(INFO) << "daemon running...";

    int sockfd = serverSocket.getSocket();

    struct pollfd fds[1]; 
    fds[0].fd = sockfd; 
    fds[0].events = POLLIN | POLLPRI;

    pthread_t threads[1];

    while (!shutdown_daemon) {
        int currNrThreads = activeThreads;
        int i = 0;
        for (; activeThreads > nrThreads; i++) {
            usleep(4000);
        }
        if (i != 0) {
            LOG(INFO) << "too many threads, slept for " << i * 4 << "ms (" << currNrThreads
                      << " threads, now " << activeThreads << ")";
        }

        // wait until there is data to read on the listen socket
        //
        int retVal = poll(fds, 1, 2000);
        if (retVal == -1) {
            LOG(WARNING) << "error in poll: " << strerror(errno);
        }

        if (retVal <= 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // open a socket to communicate with and read the header
        //
        struct sockaddr_storage clientAddr;
        unsigned int clientLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
        int connectionID = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &clientLen);
        if (connectionID == -1) {
            LOG(WARNING) << "accept return -1, error: " << strerror(errno);
            continue;
        }

        // pack the payload into buffer
        auto buf = new size_t[2];
        buf[0] = (size_t)this;
        buf[1] = (size_t)connectionID;

        int ret = pthread_create(&threads[0], &attr, &request, (void*)buf);
        if (ret != 0) {
            LOG(ERROR) << "could not start pthread, ret: '" << ret << "'";
            delete[] buf;
            continue;
        }
        // Atomic increment
        ++activeThreads; 
    }

    LOG(INFO) << "term signal received, waiting child processess to finish";

    while (activeThreads > 0) {
        LOG(INFO) << "waiting for child processes to finish...";
        sleep(1); }

    LOG(INFO) << "all child processes are finished";
}
```

with following backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  __pthread_create_2_1 (newthread=<optimized out>, attr=<optimized out>, start_routine=<optimized out>, arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:713
#1  0x00000000004621fb in Daemon::run (this=0x7ffe1715d260) at src/daemon/daemon.cpp:992
#2  0x0000000000443842 in main (argc=4, argv=0x7ffe1715d6f8) at src/myapp.cpp:991
(gdb) bt full
#0  __pthread_create_2_1 (newthread=<optimized out>, attr=<optimized out>, start_routine=<optimized out>, arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:713
        stackaddr = <optimized out>
        iattr = <optimized out>
        default_attr = {schedparam = {__sched_priority = 0}, schedpolicy = 0, flags = -1456592096, guardsize = 16,
          stackaddr = 0x409d50 <_GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN4YAML5RegExC2Ev+16>, stacksize = 140729285727984, cpuset = 0x0, cpusetsize = 0}
        free_cpuset = <optimized out>
        pd = 0x7fb373fff700
        retval = <optimized out>
        self = <optimized out>
        thread_ran = true
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "__pthread_create_2_1"
#1  0x00000000004621fb in Daemon::run (this=0x7ffe1715d260) at src/daemon/daemon.cpp:992
        currNrThreads = -1447528544
        i = 8
        retVal = 0
        clientAddr = {ss_family = 2,
          __ss_padding = "\336L\177\000\000\001", '\000' <repeats 24 times>, "\260\315\025\027\376\177\000\000\006\000\000\000\000\000\000\000daemon\000\000\b\317\025\027\376\177\000\000\320\315\025\027\376\177\000\000\n\000\000\000\000\000\000\000BackupLock\000\027\376\177\000\000\000\316\025\027\376\177\000\000!\303@\000\000\000\000\000\274\204O\000\000\000\000", __ss_align = 140729285725960}
        buf = 0x7fb300000000
        clientLen = 32691
        connectionID = 3
        attr = {__size = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\020", '\000' <repeats 37 times>, __align = 0}
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "void Daemon::run()"
        sockfd = 16
        fds = {{fd = 3, events = 3, revents = 1}}
        threads = {140408722028288}
```

How is it possible? I would understand some out of memory error, but where can error 4 happen in this code (`Ubuntu 16.04, glibc 2.2.3`)

We also suspected hardware issues so replaced all RAM on this machine but issue persisted.

Update on this: after moving software to another machine (with glibc 2.26) crashes completely stopped (under same load).

Comment: In your `pthread_create()`, shouldn't the third argument be `request` rather than `&request`? The compiler doesn't issue any warnings?

Answer (score 1):

### First of all,

I would try to replace the following:

```
// pack the payload into buffer
auto buf = new size_t[2];
buf[0] = (size_t)this;
buf[1] = (size_t)connectionID;
```

With a nice struct, like:

```
struct thread_param
{
  Daemon* deamon;
  int connectionID;
}
```

maybe I'm just paranoid, but I wouldn't use auto declaration in such as case where I'll be needed to cast it later...

### Second

it can be so many reasons to crush, and you didn't gave the whole information.

#### Does your program crash at:

1. The first iteration?
2. The second iteration?
3. The 1000th iterfation?

#### For each case it may caused by other reason:

1. You are using an uninitialized pointer.
2. You are using a deleted pointer.
3. You have a memory leak and it cause some memory allocation to failed. For example I odn't see you're deleting buf in case the pthread_create has succeeded (I guess it should be in the `request` function, and you didn't check if allocation had been succeded...)